# Lifetime trouble when slice filtering

Tags: rust

I want to optionally filter a slice without changing the type. The following approach fails:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let include: Option<HashSet<i8>> = Some(HashSet::new());
    let y: &[i8] = &[1, 2, 3];
    let z: &[i8] = match include {
        Some(set) => {
            let filtered: Vec<i8> = y.iter().filter(|&i| set.contains(i)).map(|&i| i).collect();
            filtered.as_slice()
        },
        None => y
    };
    println!("{:?}", z);
}
```

with error

```
error: `filtered` does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:10:9
   |
9  |             filtered.as_slice()
   |             -------- borrow occurs here
10 |         },
   |         ^ `filtered` dropped here while still borrowed
...
14 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

-- [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=de54009dec06699adedf03f063d7eb64&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I understand that `filtered` doesn't live long enough because the slice is simply a reference into it. I have tried to copy or clone or otherwise make a static version of the resulting `filtered.as_slice()`, but nothing compiles.

Declaring `filtered` outside of the definition of `z` won't work, because it requires `set` to do the filtering.

I expect this dance of converting to an iterator, then to a vector, and then to a slice is probably not idiomatic. So I'm interested to know of a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Declaring filtered outside of the definition of z won't work, because it requires set to do the filtering.

I don't understand why not. In the statement `filtered.as_slice()`, you borrow from `filtered`, so you must make sure `filtered` lives longer than the variable you assign it to (`z`):

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut h = HashSet::new();
    h.insert(2);
    let exclude: Option<HashSet<i8>> = Some(h);
    let y: &[i8] = &[1, 2, 3];

    let filtered: Vec<i8>;
    let z: &[i8] = match exclude {
        Some(set) => {
            filtered = y.iter().filter(|&i| !set.contains(i)).map(|&i| i).collect();
            filtered.as_slice()
        },
        None => y
    };
    println!("{:?}", z);  // outputs [1, 3]
}
```

Note I inverted the logic in `filter`.